# ng-show won't work in h2 tags, but works later in html code

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using angular with html5. I have the following code near the top of my page:

```
<h2 ng-show="stat == 'Active'">Carry On!!</h2>
 <h2 ng-hide="stat == 'Active'">Account deactivated. To reactivate, please  click <a href=""> Here.</a></h2>
```

It's part of a greeting. I basically want to check if the status of the user is active. If it is, then certain things on the page appear. If the status is deactivated, on hold, etc., then I want to tell them they need to reactivate their account to continue going. There's also a lot of account info on the page that I use ng-show/hide for that works perfectly. In sublime, I just selected all the open space where I wanted to type and typed them all up the same way so I don't think there's a problem with syntax.

For folks who still want to see what ngShow/Hide I use later, here it is:

```
<div ng-hide="stat == 'Active'"> <div class="conf"><div class="cont"></div></div></div>

          <div ng-show="stat == 'Active'">
```

Comment: Is the non-working code outside of the section marked with ng-controller? Also, why not use ng-if instead of ng-show - esp. for account info, you don't really want to leak data and just set it to not visible.

Comment: `stat` is probably outside of your scope when you are calling in and it is not working.  It is hard to tell with just a few lines of HTML. After all, you said its not a syntax problem.

Comment: Please setup a plunkr or jsfiddle

Comment: I have main tags around everything and the controller inclusion is in the main tags. I thought ngIf was no longer supported?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like your page might have some invalid markup maybe? Does it validate with the HTML5 validator?

If it does then something you can try is using an object.

In your controller do something like:

```
var ctrlObj = {stat: 'Active'};
```

Then in your markup do:

```
<div ng-show="ctrlObj.stat == 'Active'"></div>
```

There is a good article somewhere on the web arguing the case for never using double equals. I haven't used one in over 2 years since. === does type checking too. Makes for more robust code.

Also there's an article on ng saying if you're not using the dot (as in my example) you're doing something wrong. Has helped me a lot.